# Python: Extracting data from a .seg file

Tags: python, data-extraction

I have this `.seg` file from which I need to extract the values in 3rd and 4th column based on cluster number, e.g. `S0`.

```
;; cluster S0 
khatija-ankle 1 0 184 F S U S0
;; cluster S1 
khatija-ankle 1 407 291 F S U S1
khatija-ankle 1 790 473 F S U S1
khatija-ankle 1 1314 248 F S U S1
khatija-ankle 1 1663 187 F S U S1
```

Here is my code so far:

```
file1 = open('f1.seg', "w")
file2 = open('f2.seg', "w")

with open('ankle.seg','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if word == 'S0':
            file1.write(word)
        elif word == 'S1':
            file2.write(word)
```

How do I create a file of each cluster and write the 3rd and 4th columns in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While of course this can be done in Python, it's a perfect illustration of why awk is so well suited to slashing through text files:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
/^;;/ {
      filename = $3 ".seg"
      next
}

{ print $3, $4 > filename }
```

Output:

```
$ tail *.seg
==> S0.seg <==
0 184

==> S1.seg <==
407 291
790 473
1314 248
1663 187
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: How do I create a file of each cluster and write the 3rd and 4th columns in it?

Instead to compare single column value `if word == 'S0':`, check which cluster id has the last column of a line of data.

For example:

```
# Create a list of column values
data = line.rstrip().split()

# Condition: last value in data == cluster id
if data[-1] == 'S0':
    # write to S0 file
    print("file1.write({})".format(data[2:4]))

elif data[-1] == 'S1':
    # write to S1 file
    print("file2.write({})".format(data[2:4]))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> file1.write(['S0'])
> file1.write(['0', '184'])
> file2.write(['S1'])
> file2.write(['407', '291'])
> file2.write(['790', '473'])
> file2.write(['1314', '248'])
> file2.write(['1663', '187'])
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***